# How to open a file batch file that is up above in a different folder from the batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

Here is what I have:

```
call cd .. file.bat
```

and it does not work. What do I do?

Comment: ..\file.bat         ..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either:

```
cd ..
call file.bat
```

don't call `cd` but `file.bat` and use two lines or concate the commands properly:

```
cd .. & call file.bat
```

or:

```
call ..\file.bat
```

or use absolute path:

```
call "c:\my directory\subdir\file.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the **'path'** environment variable.

include the directory where your **'file.bat'** resides in your path variable.  Then, when you want to 'call' it, you only need to say 'call file.bat' and the OS will do the rest for you.

Maybe this solution is not applicable to your problem, but i myself found it useful to place often called BAT files in one directory and point to that directory by

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\MyBatFiles
```

This will append your directory to the existing path variable.

Typing **HELP PATH** at the command prompt will provide some help about this